# make clear directions vs. recognize directions

Tags: phrase-usage

I want to use "make clear of" to express the meaning of "Can you recognize directions in darkness?":

Can you make clear of directions in darkness?

Am I on the right track of using the phrase "make clear of" here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Make clear of" is not a colloquial phrase. "Can you [make out](https://www.lexico.com/definition/make_out) the words?" is common. So is "I made clear my objections to your plan". "To make clear" means "to explain". "I thought I had made it clear that dogs are not allowed."